# ReactNative - Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: react-native, android-studio, npm, navigation-drawer, yarn-lock.json

I face this error when I'm try to use Drawer Component.

And There is nothing in simualtor screen.

My error message is as follow

```
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  // plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "rn220720",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.7.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

- My Android Version is Pixel_4_XL_API_31

### What I did for solving this code

1. Before running this project I deleted emulator in the android studio
2. In Cmd Window, I typed 'npm cache clean --force' to get rid of npm cache at the project root folder
3. In Cmd Window, I typed '.\gradlew clean' to delete things about compiled project in android folder
4. Restart Computer booting.

Additionally, I think there is dependency trouble with npm. So, I change package mangement tool as
yarn. But  The problem is appeared again